# Recovery mode shell prompt with read-only file system?

Tags: filesystem, read-only, recovery-mode

I'm trying to install a video driver on my Ubuntu 16.04 system, and the instructions caution me to set runlevel to prevent the X server from starting. Using what was posted in [my other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254223/unable-to-mount-filesystem-as-read-write-in-recovery-mode) I've had problems doing that, so as a workaround I decided to boot to recovery mode and use the "root shell prompt" option.

This worked fine until I tried to run the run file and fouond that I forgot to set the executable bit.

I entered a cdmod command. It came back with the message "readonly file system."

So I have to return to the X server to start a terminal window and set the executable bit.

Except that once I do, I won't be able to use the run file anyway because it has to write files to do its job.

So recovery mode gives me root access but makes the file system read only? What? Is this some kind of stupid joke?

Comment: Yes, it's a stupid joke to mount the fs read-only in case of possible filesystem corruption.

Comment: If you've had _problems_, of which you've told us nothing, booting to run level 3, then before adding things to the system, maybe you should be fixing the system. Run level 3 is __way__ more important than game quality video is.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver - he asked about run levels half an hour before he posted this over here: http://askubuntu.com/q/893505/631140

As far as I know he never ever really tried to get to run level 3 the correct way.

Comment: @user62475 That sort of figures. Maybe this Q needs to have a reference to that Q.